# Clearing Saved Logins

Tags: gmail, password

I have a Nexus 5x that is proving quite troublesome (overheating/rebooting) and needs to be sent back to supplier/manufacturer. Before I send it I would like to removed saved logins and passwords. These are for the Gmail account linked to the phone and a number of professional websites - there are confidentiality issues. Can this be done or would I be best just changing the passwords from another system?

Comment: I would like to mention that Google offers a way to users to revoke access from apps/browsers where your Google ID is signed in. Visit https://myaccount.google.com/device-activity

Answer (score 1):

You can do a simple factory data reset. That's a good enough bet.

Additionally, even if you don't reset it manually, it'll likely be reset by the repair shop.

Comment: Does the reset remov e the data? I cannot access the device from  either a Windows or Linux laptop as I did with my previous Android (Samsung Galaxy)